# Get and set the default wifi connection and connect to it

Tags: c#, windows, networking, .net-2.0, wifi

I need to get and set the default wifi connection from a nic list (I get them with devcon on XP and wmic on Windows 7). Then if it's possible, connect to that nic.

I'm working on .NET 2.0 for compatibility issues.

No, I can't use any "out of windows" mod, library, control, etc. Just APIs and .NET 2.0

It's not important because I can translate the code or the way to C#, just for information: I'm developing on .NET 2005 Visual Studio and C#

Comment: Why are you stuck with .NET 2.0 in mid 2012?

Comment: Client requirement

Comment: Are you tried the [`Native Wifi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API?

Comment: For what I read, the min requisite for Native Wifi is XP SP2 (3.5), I need something for XP (2.0).